# Full outer join not working

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL server database that I think that im having a problem with a join, but it may not be a join issue. It is a simple Stored Proc

```
ALTER Proc [dbo].[proc_Time_NotEntered]
(
@sDate datetime,
@eDate datetime
)
AS
BEGIN
    Select (e.[emplname] + ', ' + e.[empfName]) as [FullName],
           wip.wdate as [date],
          Sum(case when wip.wdate between @sDate and @eDate and wip.windicator <> 'D' then wip.[whours] else 0 end) as [Hours],
          dept.[DeptName]

    From sab.dbo.employee as e
    Join sab.dbo.wip as wip on e.[ID] = wip.wempID
    join sab.dbo.department as dept on e.empdept = dept.deptID

    where
        wip.wdate between @sDate and @eDate
        and e.[emplname] + ', ' + e.[empfName] <>  ' No Selection, '
    Group by 
        e.[emplname],
        e.[empfName],
        dept.[DeptName],
        wip.[wdate]
    ORDER BY
    -- wip.[wdate],
     e.[emplname] + ', ' + e.[empfName]
    return 1
END
```

With My joins I have tried full outer join and getting same results.

What I'm trying to accomplish: I would like to get all of the employees even if they have no hours for each day.

Comment: Isn't that just a left join? Full outer join would give you hours that have no employees as well, I doubt that makes sense in your data model?

Comment: no it doesn't, I was just trying to get all of the employees then I would have worried about the hours.

Answer (score 1):

You need a left join to return employees with no matching wip records.

```
Select e.emplname, wip.wdate 
From sab.dbo.employee as e
Left Join sab.dbo.wip as wip on e.[ID] = wip.wempID and wip.wdate between @sDate and @eDate
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things.  First, `JOIN` all by itself is an inner join.  If you want all employees and everything else is optional:

```
select...
from
employees e
left join wip
on e.[ID] = wip.wempID
and wip.wdate between @sDate and @eDate
```

**You need to move the constraint on wip to the on clause, because otherwise you will end up with an inner join still.**

Comment: The downvote was because before you edited your answer, it was wrong. Can't speak about the downvote on the other answer though

Comment: this still doesn't return all of the employees

Comment: @user3120232 Unless there are other tables to get the employess, it's not possible that this exact query doesn't return all them, what other filters are you using?

Comment: Also, did you put the and wip.wdate in the where clause, or is it part of the on clause, because it won't return all employees if the wdate restrictions are in the where clause.

Comment: it is in the where clause

Comment: Well there you go then, you have to remove it from the where clause and include it in the on clause.